# C# / .NET built-in interfaces list

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I'm looking for full C# standard interfaces list. I'm almost sure that such topic was posted somewhere on MSDN, but I can't find it. Does anyone has a reference?

Comment: Without more details I can only do a basic google search http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by standard interfaces?

Comment: A full list of standard interfaces to implement.

Comment: there is no such list, you choose what interfaces you need to implement, depending on the problem you need to solve.

Comment: Please read the FAQ first, your question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: But there are some predefined interfaces like IEnumerable, IComparable,... much more. I'm looking for overview of these built-in implementations, which are useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im sorry but such doc does not exist...

See, msdn documentation is organized by "namespaces", so... you can see that such document would not fit anywhere... 
by the way, why would you want that?!? if you compile the documents of each interface in the basics dll (system, text, system.data, linq, etc...) you would have a quite large document that would cause more confusion than "de-confusion", since in diferent namespaces interfaces may have the same name...

Comment: I want to write my own priority queue classes. I was looking for some predefined interfaces that could describe such data models.

Comment: Ahhhh you should've said that at first!!! i sugest you check the System.Collections namespace! best of luck! and btw theres alot of tutorials... check em out! they might help you...

Comment: Yey. That's the thing I've searched for. Sorry for confusing question, I'm new to .NET programming. btw. What tutorials did you meant (may you give me some link ?). Thanks.

Comment: check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126751/Priority-queue-in-C-with-the-help-of-heap-data-str